# CSS Text margins vh

Tags: html, css

I was working on a project and started working on texts when I realized that if a set the `margin-top: 20vh` property on `CSS` does not work, why? Please help me.

```css
#text1 {
  margin-top: 26vh;
}

#text2 {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15mm;
  margin-top: 22vh;
}

#text3 {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 37vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="imagesUnderHeader" id="image2" style="background-image: url(Images/Loop.gif)">
  <div class="progressionBar" id="progressionBar"></div>
  <div class="dots" id="firstParagraph"></div>
  <div class="dots" id="secondParagraph"></div>
  <div class="dots" id="thirdParagraph"></div>
  <div class="paragraphBar" id="bar1"></div>
  <div class="paragraphBar" id="bar2"></div>
  <div class="paragraphBar" id="bar3"></div>
  <h1 class="title adjustPadding goUpText" id="title">Some Text</h1><br>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text1">Subtitle 1</p><br>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text2">Subtitle 2</p><br>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text3">Subtitle 3, <a> with a link, </a> <a>Another one</a><br> <a>and another one</a></p>
</section>
```

If you need any informations please ask and I will provide additional informations, thank you so much for the help.

Comment: but your code works as intended !

Comment: Are you sure? I tried using this and then resizing the page vertically but I feel like the text is remaining in the same place and not moving as I resize it...
i wanna use it to resize the section based on the height of the screen it's running on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made a demo stripping away some details from your code that were just adding noise for the sake of better showing what's going on.

As the mdn docs says:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units

> 1vh = 1% of the viewport's height

I included that quote just to avoid any ambiguity but it was pretty clear already.

In this demo I just used one single custom css property to decide the `margin-top` value and used that value to set the `margin-top` of all the 3 `#text` elements and to size the `::before` element used as a placeholder to highlight the margin like it was a ruler.

The value of that variable is going to be `10vh` so 10% of viewport's height.

As you can see running the demo at full screen, if you resize the window, those distances ***will indeed change*** as expected.

```css
:root {
  --margin-top: 10vh;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  margin-top: var(--margin-top);
}

.title {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.subtitle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--margin-top);
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 0px;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--margin-top) - 1px); /*here it's doing -1px to account for border*/
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="imagesUnderHeader" id="image2">
  <h1 class="title adjustPadding goUpText" id="title">Some Text</h1>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text1">Subtitle 1</p>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text2">Subtitle 2</p>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text3">
    Subtitle 3,
    <a> with a link, </a>
    <a>Another one</a>
    <br>
    <a>and another one</a>
  </p>
</section>
```

Anyway the whole truth is also that I removed the `<br>`s that were going to add vertical spaces hard to discern from margins and more importantly I also removed the `float` `left` and `right` because they affect the positioning in relation to the document flow.

So for the sake of completeness this is the same exact demo with those styles added to show the difference:

```css
:root {
  --margin-top: 10vh;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding; 0;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  margin-top: var(--margin-top);
}

#text2{
  float: left;
}

#text3{
  float: right;
}

.title {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.subtitle {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.subtitle::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--margin-top);
  border: solid 1px red;
  width: 0px;
  top: calc(-1 * var(--margin-top) - 1px); /*here it's doing -1px to account for border*/
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="imagesUnderHeader" id="image2">
  <h1 class="title adjustPadding goUpText" id="title">Some Text</h1>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text1">Subtitle 1</p>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text2">Subtitle 2</p>
  <p class="subtitle adjustPadding popUpText" id="text3">
    Subtitle 3,
    <a> with a link, </a>
    <a>Another one</a>
    <br>
    <a>and another one</a>
  </p>
</section>
```

So to make it short, to me the margin is correctly applied. So I'm not sure I'm answering to the exact issue you are encountering. As an added consideration maybe you are fighting against the margin collapsing and in case that's an option, here is the related info from mdn:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: I'll try and let you know, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: if you accepted the answer it was appreciated

Comment: I forgot sorry.